# How to set a dependency of html page layout on media type?

Tags: html, css

A, B are sections (created as a table) in html. I need to display them in some way on screen and the other way on the print. Further on, A and B have two subsections: A', A'' and B', B'' (where each of them is nonempty and A=A'A''; B=B'B'' which means that A equals A' proceeded by A'' (the same for B)). 
On screen I'd like to display A first and then B (here subsections are not relevant). 
On print I would like to have 2 pages, where first page contains A', B' sections (in the given order) and second page contains A'', B''.

screen: A B

printed page:
1st page: A'B'

2nd page: A''B''

Is there anyway to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I did understand correctly what you mean: you have to declare some CSS to hide sections on screen and a specific one to add a page break:

```
@media screen {
    .print-only {
        display: none;
    }
}

.page-break {
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

Then you can use them:

```
<article>
    <section class="print-only">A'</section>
    <section class="print-only">B'</section>
    <span class="print-only page-break></span>
    <section class="print-only">A''</section>
    <section class="print-only">B''</section>
</article>
```

All sections will be visible when printed (only) and there will be a page-break between A'B' and A''B''. Now you have to change their order. This isn't portable (you may need to use vendor specific prefixes (`-moz`, `-ms`, `-webkit`), here I show CSS3 syntax:

```
@media screen {
    .print-only {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media print {
    article {
        display: box;
    }

    section {
        box-orient: vertical;
    }

    .first-page {
        box-ordinal-group: 1;
    }

    .first-page:last {
        page-break-after: always;
    }

    .second-page {
        box-ordinal-group: 2;
    }
}
```

Your HTML will then be:

```
<article>
    <section class="first-page">A'</section>
    <section class="second-page">B'</section>
    <section class="first-page">A''</section>
    <section class="second-page">B''</section>
</article>
```

Comment: I would like to have sth like this: 
if (display on screen) then 
  show sections in this order: A'A''B'B'' 
if (print) 
  show sections A'B' on 1st page; sections A''B'' on 2nd page.

So, your suggestion might be used to fix the problem, but I'm looking for other, more consice solution.

Comment: @Jakub now, I understand what you mean. Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

To define different styles for *print* and *screen*, use the CSS `@media` rule.

```
@media print {
    /* 
       Style(s) for print
    */
}

@media screen {
    /* 
       Style(s) for screen
    */
}

@media all {
    /* 
       Style(s) for all media
    */
}
```

[MDN @media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)